# Corda: TwoPartyTradeFlow throws Exception "Failed requirement: "

Tags: corda

I’ve recently recreated the trader-demo in Java. For some reason the transaction doesn’t work and the error: “java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed requirement.” is thrown, without further information (normally I would expect to see which requirement failed). The code runs through until it calls the TwoPartyTradeFlow.Seller.

This is my code in the flow. The flow gets called from an API which passes the "amount" and "otherParty". I am retrieving a Commercial Paper that I issued in another flow, which then belongs to the seller who wants to trade it with a buyer Party.

```
public Seller(int amount, Party otherParty) {
            this.buyerParty = otherParty;
            this.amount = amount;
        }

@Suspendable
@Override
public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {
    ServiceHub serviceHub = getServiceHub();
    Logger logger = getLogger();
    FlowSession otherPartySession = initiateFlow(buyerParty);

    StateAndRef<CommercialPaper.State> cp = serviceHub.getVaultService().queryBy(CommercialPaper.State.class).getStates().stream().findFirst().get();

    Amount<Currency> amountWithCurr = new Amount<>(amount, CHF);
    PartyAndCertificate cpOwner = serviceHub.getKeyManagementService().freshKeyAndCert(getOurIdentityAndCert(), false);
    final OpaqueBytes ref = OpaqueBytes.of((byte) 0x01);
    PartyAndReference partyAndReference = new PartyAndReference(cpOwner.getParty(), ref);

    progressTracker.setCurrentStep(RECEIVING_CASH);
    otherPartySession.send(amount);

    progressTracker.setCurrentStep(TRADING);

    TwoPartyTradeFlow.Seller seller = new TwoPartyTradeFlow.Seller(
            otherPartySession, cp, amountWithCurr, cpOwner, progressTracker.getChildProgressTracker(TRADING)
    );
    return subFlow(seller);
    }
```

}

This is the Stacktrace:

```
[1;31mE 13:59:46+0200 [qtp527148155-115] template.DVPApi.throwException - 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed requirement.
[m java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed requirement.
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.get(CordaFutureImpl.kt) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.template.DVPApi.createDVP(DVPApi.java:152) [cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841) [jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535) [jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) [jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:561) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279) [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104) [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124) [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed requirement.
```

And here is the Code of the CommercialPaper Issue flow in case it issues the CommercialPaper in a wrong way and causes the the TwoPartyTradeFlow to fail.

```
public CommercialPaperIssueFlow(CordaX500Name recipientName, CordaX500Name issuerName, Amount<Currency> price) {
        this.recipientName = recipientName;
        this.issuerName = issuerName;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Suspendable
    @Override
    public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {

        ServiceHub serviceHub = getServiceHub();
        final Party notary = serviceHub.getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);
        final Party recipient = serviceHub.getNetworkMapCache().getPeerByLegalName(recipientName);
        final Party issuer = serviceHub.getNetworkMapCache().getPeerByLegalName(issuerName);
        CommercialPaper abstractCP = new CommercialPaper();

        PartyAndReference partyAndReference = new PartyAndReference(issuer, ref);

        Instant maturityDate = Instant.MAX;

        final Amount<Issued<Currency>> faceValue = new Amount<Issued<Currency>>(price.getQuantity(),
                price.getDisplayTokenSize(),
                new Issued<Currency>(partyAndReference,
                        price.getToken()));


        TransactionBuilder cpBuilder = abstractCP.generateIssue(partyAndReference,
                faceValue, maturityDate, notary);

        progressTracker.setCurrentStep(ISSUING_CP);
        cpBuilder.setTimeWindow(Instant.now(), Duration.ofSeconds(100));
        SignedTransaction partiallySignedCP = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(cpBuilder);

        SignedTransaction signedCP = subFlow(new FinalityFlow(partiallySignedCP));


        progressTracker.setCurrentStep(MOVING_CP);
        // Make transaction to move it to a new key
        TransactionBuilder transactionBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);
        abstractCP.generateMove(transactionBuilder, signedCP.getTx().outRef(0), recipient);
        SignedTransaction partiallySignedMoveCP = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(transactionBuilder);
        return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(partiallySignedMoveCP));
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided, because I really have no idea why this error happens.

Edit:
Here is the Stacktrace from the log file:

```
[WARN ] 2018-05-09T17:09:12,893Z [Node thread] utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMap.set - Double insert in net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMap for entity class class net.corda.node.services.identity.PersistentIdentityService$PersistentIdentityNames key C=US,L=New York,O=JonesBank, not inserting the second time
[WARN ] 2018-05-09T17:09:13,133Z [Node thread] flow.[13b767a6-8cd1-4747-867e-7ffe04ed99cb].run - Terminated by unexpected exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed requirement.
    at net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker.setCurrentStep(ProgressTracker.kt:108) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.template.TxInitiatorFlow$Seller.call(TxInitiatorFlow.java:91) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
    at com.template.TxInitiatorFlow$Seller.call(TxInitiatorFlow.java:26) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:41) [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:69) [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
[WARN ] 2018-05-09T17:09:13,543Z [Node thread] statemachine.StateMachineManager.onExistingSessionMessage - Received a session message for unknown session: SessionReject(initiatorSessionId=2776640309751674301, errorMessage=Unable to establish session), from C=GB,L=London,O=CreditSuisse
[INFO ] 2018-05-09T17:12:41,044Z [Node thread] vault.NodeVaultService._queryBy - Vault Query for contract type: class net.corda.finance.contracts.CommercialPaper$State, criteria: VaultQueryCriteria(status=UNCONSUMED, contractStateTypes=null, stateRefs=null, notary=null, softLockingCondition=null, timeCondition=null), pagination: PageSpecification(pageNumber=-1, pageSize=200), sorting: Sort(columns=[])
[WARN ] 2018-05-09T17:12:41,174Z [Node thread] utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMap.set - Double insert in net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMap for entity class class net.corda.node.services.identity.PersistentIdentityService$PersistentIdentityNames key C=US,L=New York,O=JonesBank, not inserting the second time
[WARN ] 2018-05-09T17:12:41,265Z [Node thread] flow.[71832083-4910-416e-abb6-34a0cacfa7a5].run - Terminated by unexpected exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed requirement.
    at net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker.setCurrentStep(ProgressTracker.kt:108) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.template.TxInitiatorFlow$Seller.call(TxInitiatorFlow.java:91) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
    at com.template.TxInitiatorFlow$Seller.call(TxInitiatorFlow.java:26) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:41) [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:69) [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
[WARN ] 2018-05-09T17:12:41,368Z [Node thread] statemachine.StateMachineManager.onExistingSessionMessage - Received a session message for unknown session: SessionReject(initiatorSessionId=7653034215696783817, errorMessage=Unable to establish session), from C=GB,L=London,O=CreditSuisse
```

The part:

```
at net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker.setCurrentStep(ProgressTracker.kt:108) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.template.TxInitiatorFlow$Seller.call(TxInitiatorFlow.java:91) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
    at com.template.TxInitiatorFlow$Seller.call(TxInitiatorFlow.java:26) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
```

This is the relevant part I think. This occurs when progressTracker.setCurrentStep(TRADING) is called in the flow.
I initialized this step like this:

```
private final ProgressTracker.Step TRADING = new ProgressTracker.Step("Starting the trade flow") {
            @Override public ProgressTracker childProgressTracker() {
                return TwoPartyTradeFlow.Seller.Companion.tracker();
            }
        };
```

Edit 2:
Now since I got rid of this Exception, there is still an another Error that prevents the Trade to take place. The Counterparty rejects the session request with this Exception: `net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Party C=GB,L=London,O=CreditSuisse rejected session request: Unable to establish session`.
Here is the newest Stacktrace:

```
[INFO ] 2018-05-13T12:53:08,723Z [Node thread] flow.[5b805998-3822-49b3-b12f-4bb306cbbc49].call - successfully instantiated seller, now invoking
[WARN ] 2018-05-13T12:53:08,997Z [Node thread] flow.[5b805998-3822-49b3-b12f-4bb306cbbc49].run - Terminated by unexpected exception
net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Party C=GB,L=London,O=CreditSuisse rejected session request: Unable to establish session
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.waitForConfirmation(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:309) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.getConfirmedSessionIfPresent(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:344) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.sendAndReceive(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:182) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.FlowStateMachine$DefaultImpls.sendAndReceive$default(FlowStateMachine.kt:28) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.sendAndReceive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:22) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.DataVendingFlow.sendPayloadAndReceiveDataRequest(SendTransactionFlow.kt:70) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.DataVendingFlow.call(SendTransactionFlow.kt:48) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.DataVendingFlow.call(SendTransactionFlow.kt:31) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:243) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.finance.flows.TwoPartyTradeFlow$Seller.call(TwoPartyTradeFlow.kt:84) ~[corda-finance-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.finance.flows.TwoPartyTradeFlow$Seller.call(TwoPartyTradeFlow.kt:58) ~[corda-finance-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:243) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.template.TxInitiatorFlow$Seller.call(TxInitiatorFlow.java:83) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
    at com.template.TxInitiatorFlow$Seller.call(TxInitiatorFlow.java:25) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:41) [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:69) [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
```

The Error gets thrown in the seller Flow when calling `return subFlow(seller);`

And for completeness, here is the flow of the counterparty:

```
@InitiatedBy(Seller.class)
    public static class Buyer extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {
        private FlowSession otherPartyFlow;
        private Logger logger = getLogger();

        public Buyer(FlowSession otherPartyFlow) {
            this.otherPartyFlow = otherPartyFlow;
        }

        private final ProgressTracker.Step SENDING_CASH = new ProgressTracker.Step("Sending Cash");

        private final ProgressTracker progressTracker = new ProgressTracker(SENDING_CASH);

        @Suspendable
        @Override
        public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException{
            ServiceHub serviceHub = getServiceHub();


            progressTracker.setCurrentStep(SENDING_CASH);
            Amount<Currency> amount = otherPartyFlow.receive(Amount.class).unwrap(data -> data);


            Party notary = serviceHub.getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);
            TwoPartyTradeFlow.Buyer buyer = new TwoPartyTradeFlow.Buyer(
                    otherPartyFlow, notary, amount, CommercialPaper.State.class
            );

            SignedTransaction tradeTX = subFlow(buyer);

            return tradeTX;
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with my session?

Comment: There should be another part to the stack trace, which identifies the error as being thrown from a certain line in the flow?

Comment: @joel: I edited my question and added the stacktrace from the log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown by this piece of `ProgressTracker` code: `net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker.setCurrentStep(ProgressTracker.kt:108)`.

This corresponds to the following lines:

```
val index = steps.indexOf(value)
require(index != -1)
```

When the `require` condition fails, you get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed requirement.`

The `require` condition fails in this case because the step you're trying to set (`value` here) does not exist as a `ProgressTracker` step (i.e. its index in the list of `steps` is `-1`.

Please check that you have included the progress tracker step in your `ProgressTracker`, as done here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/java-source/src/main/java/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.java#L59.

I've opened a PR to improve future error messages of this sort, here: https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/3116.

Comment: Thank you for this. Indeed I hadn't included this step in my ProgressTracker. I now got rid of this error.

Comment: However, it isn't the only error. As you can see in the stacktrace, there was another error concerning the session (last line). I added more info in the question.

Comment: Thanks. You'd now need to look at the logs of the `CreditSuisse` node to see why it rejected the session.

Comment: looking at the credit suisse log gave me the relevant information. the TraderFlow now runs successfully. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The session was rejected from the other node because of this statement: `private Logger logger = getLogger();` in the Buyer flow. I got the logger before it actually entered the flow (Maybe it was trying to bind the logger to a flow that didn't yet exist or something). Moving it to the call method did it and works now.